# How do you get a service star for the Medkit?

Tags: battlefield-3

I play assault and I drop the Medikit liberally. Unfortunately, I've never seen the exp bar increase. There even appears to be a service star icon next to the kit on the equipment selection screen... how would one go about obtaining it?

Comment: isn't the medical ribbon and 50 ribbon medal enough?

Comment: It may be enough, but he is just wondering how to level it up. There may possibly be upgrades for it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's bugged (or unimplemented).  [Others](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/a_d/battlefield_3/f/1829/t/127435.aspx) are reporting the same thing.  If you're throwing out medkits and getting points for healing your teammates, and it's still not moving, it might not be enabled.